# How do I get WebSecurity.Login to work?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to get the default login model for MVC4 working, but out of the box, I don't think I'm doing it right.  This is the default code:

```
if (WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
{
    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

When I build, run and try to log in, I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WebMatrix.WebData.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: To call this method, the "Membership.Provider" property must be an instance of "ExtendedMembershipProvider".
```

I thought it was an issue with my provider resources, but I've installed Entity First Tools 6.0.2, System.web.providers, and Microsoft.aspnet.providers.core and am still getting this issue.  I found some indications, it might be because I'm connecting to a SQL database, but I couldn't find a resolution.

Someone indicated I need to use System.Web.Http instead of System.Web.Mvc, but that wasn't it.

This is my connection string:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=servername;Initial Catalog=mercury;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

This is my profile and membership info:

```
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

I read something else indicating I needed to initialize my SimpleMembershipProvier, but I have a custom initializer built to run from application_start so I an seed my database with data:

```
Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(new DatabaseInitializer());
new UsersContext().UserProfiles.Find(1);
```

My data initializer has this code to initialize my database:

```
private void SeedMembership()
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("UsersContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
```

So, I have no idea where to look at next.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few places where things could have gone wrong. For starters I'd downgrade Entity 6 to Entity 5 since EF 6 is made to support MVC which uses the Claims Identity model rather than Simple Membership API. You can go to package manager console and choose the relevant app

```
Uninstall-Package EntityFramework Version 6.0.2
```

then

```
Install-Package EntityFramework version 5.0.0
```

Hope this gets you going.
You can also wrap the Initializer in a check method

```
if(!Websecurity.Initialized){

///Initialize Websecurity
}
```

Comment: I can't uninstall it, because of dependencies on Microsoft.aspnet.providers.core.  I think I'm getting this error, because I have a custom userprofile database with missing table columns.